# getting array from DB null result

Tags: php, mysqli

im trying to get some data from my DB.

My problem is that i get null pointer on my array when i try to get the data.

When i run my sql command in phpmyadmin i get good results.

I also checked with `echo` that `$ids[$i]` isnt null.

The error message:

```
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

Thanks for helping.

This is my code:

```
while($i <  $size)
    { 

    $mysqli = new mysqli(****);

    $sql = "SELECT workout_name, user, likes, dislikes, date FROM workouts_wall WHERE id_for_wall = ? "; 

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$sql]");

    $stmt->bind_param('i', $ids[$i]);

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();

    $stmt->bind_result($workout_name, $user, $likes, $dislikes, $date);

    if($stmt->fetch())
    {   
       // temp user array
       $workouts = array();

        $workouts["workout_name"] = $workout_name;
        $workouts["picture"] = getPicture($user);
        $workouts["user"] = $user;
        $workouts["likes"] = $likes;
        $workouts["dislikes"] = $dislikes;
        $workouts["date"] = $date;

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["workouts"], $workouts);
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `$response["workouts"]` itself is not instantiated as an array, so [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) does not recognize it as an array. Try adding this before your `while` loop:

```
$response["workouts"] = array();
```

Since you're only adding a single element at a time to the array, it's easier and simpler to just use the following code (instead of the `array_push` call):

```
$response["workouts"][] = $workouts;
```

Comment: I tried it. and now i get this error on my android app:

`Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 0 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject 0`
Why it thinks its an int array?

Comment: @dasdasd I have no idea what's going on in your Android app, but that's the subject for another question, as your Java code may have separate issues of its own.